# What's the meaning of "straight" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, meaning

> Thats some **straight** blockbuster movie sh-t. They deserve it if they pulled it off.

What's the meaning of *straight* here? The comment was made in response to a news article on a [bank robbery](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2264567/Robbers-tunnel-100ft-underground-break-Volksbank-Berlin.html) in which the robbery was done by the robbers professionally dug a tunnel underground through to the bank's vault.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unadulterated, pure. There is nothing to it that is not "blockbuster movie sh-t", for it does not deviate from the straight path of "blockbuster movie sh-t" but at all times keeps to being "blockbuster movie sh-t".

(Even with the censoring, that was a fun sentence to write).

Comment: I would use undoubtedly as synonym, because we are not movie critics to know the genres so well, neither do the ordinary viewer.

Comment: @speedyGonzales since it was used as a metaphor for a real-life event, we don't need to be. I wouldn't use *undoubtedly* because I won't deny someone the opinion of doubting it, since it's not stated as literally true.

Answer (score 3):

The comment could be rephrased as

> Such a stunt looks as though it's straight out of a blockbuster movie.

*Straight* is slang for "complete" in this case, so it could also be read as

> That's complete blockbuster movie sh-t... they deserve it.

The comment's author is probably impressed with the robbers.

Answer (score 2):

It's a shortening of *straight up*, which in this context means *pure* or *honest*.

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/straight+up

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RJ7J0SwK8fE